# Set and get methods in java

Tags: java, methods, get, set, jgrasp

```
public class Examples
{
    private int numbers[]; //instance variable
    public Examples()
    {
        numbers = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
        {                           //constructor number 1
           numbers[i] = 42;
        }
     } 

     public Examples(int[] array)
     {
        numbers = new int[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
           numbers[i] = array[i];         //constructor number 2
        }
      }
}
```

So i have to write a set method that will create a new array for the instance variable that is the same length as as the array passed to setNumbers and then copy values of its parameter..

so far, i have

```
public void setNumbers (int numbers)
    {
        int[] setNumbers = int numbers;
    }
```

and I get errors from that, not sure why

Comment: public void setNumbers (int numbers)
  {
   int[] setNumbers = int numbers;
  }

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far in your setNumbers method and explain what roadblock you have hit.

Comment: What did you do to try to resolve this yourself?

Comment: post the test code(normally in your main method) and also the error!

Comment: Alright I re-edited it :) 
As for the error message i receive, it says that int numbers is expected to have '.class' which i don't think is right..

Comment: You can't apply the `new` operator to an integer variable; it only applies to constructor calls. `new numbers` doesn't qualify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your setter method signature is supposed to be, but the correct method might be one of these:

```
public void setNumbers (int []numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
    // or perhaps you need to copy the argument:
    // this.numbers = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length);
}
```

or else:

```
public void setNumbers (int numbers) {
    this.numbers = new int[numbers];
}
```

Also, I would write your constructors like this:

```
public Examples()
{
    numbers = new int[10];
    Arrays.fill(numbers, 42);
 } 

 public Examples(int[] array)
 {
    numbers = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
  }
```

Comment: @user1804737 - Don't forget to import `java.util.Arrays` if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I think he might want to copy the argument array to `numbers` in the `setNumbers` method as opposed to just assign it.